# Is there option to run 2 flows one after another in metaflow?

Tags: python, netflix-metaflow

Only flow1 runs. I'm trying to find a way to run flow1 and when finished to run flow2. flow2 should be with scheduler. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
'''
import metaflow
from metaflow import FlowSpec, Parameter, step

class   Flow1(FlowSpec):
    @step
    def start(self):
        print(1)
        self.next(self.step1)
    @step
    def step1(self):
        print(2)
        self.next(self.end)
    @step
    def end(self):
        print("First flow finished")
class Flow2(FlowSpec):
    @step
    def start(self):
        print(1.1)
        self.next(self.end)
    @step
    def end(self):
        print("Second flow finished")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flow1 = Flow1()
    flow1.run()
    flow2 = Flow2()
    flow2.run()
'''
```